# How to filter by boolean value in Gatling JSONPath expression?

Tags: gatling, jsonpath

How to filter by boolean value in JSONPath expression?

I'm using this site which fails to validate my expression and I am looking for an explanation why:  https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#

My JSON is

```
{
  "whatever" : {
    "best" : {
      "reward" : "true"
    } 
  } 
}
```

And my expression, which fails to match (in Gatling, not validator site), is either of these:

```
$.whatever.best[?(@.reward=='true')]
$.whatever.best[?(@.reward==true)]
```

This expression works fine:

```
$.whatever.best.reward
```

And strangely, this works:

```
$..*[?(@.reward==true)]
```

What is wrong?   Please no guesses.  I provided the site in order to verify your answer.

The instructions here did not help me:  https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

The implementation used in the online evaluator you're mentioning is broken.

The `$.whatever.best[?(@.reward=='true')]` expression is correct as `"true"` is not a JSON boolean value but a String one.
Gatling implementation is correct and works as expected.

Comment: I have this matching problem not only on that broken validator site, but in my Gatling code itself.  I had to use the wildcard as a workaround.  Trying to understand why but your answer here is not enough info.   If you can point me to a unit test that proves it, I would be satisfied.   Otherwise, when i get some time I'll provide a unit test that proves otherwise and ill update my question.